# Vite & Sveltekit: Unresponsive white website

Tags: svelte, vite, sveltekit

When running Sveltekit's barebone skeleton app using `npm run dev` my terminal freezes up as soon as I open the localhost:5173 website. The website loads forever until eventually I get a message:

```
<--- JS stacktrace --->

FATAL ERROR: Reached heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x7f8bac93f268 node::Abort() [/usr/lib64/libnode.so.93]
 2: 0x7f8bac82cb89  [/usr/lib64/libnode.so.93]
 3: 0x7f8badb36a00 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/lib64/libnode.so.93]
 4: 0x7f8badb36dc7 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/lib64/libnode.so.93]
 5: 0x7f8badcf67e5  [/usr/lib64/libnode.so.93]
 6: 0x7f8badd0c654  [/usr/lib64/libnode.so.93]
 7: 0x7f8badd0e749 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithLightRetrySlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/lib64/libnode.so.93]
 8: 0x7f8badd0e7d7 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFailSlowPath(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/lib64/libnode.so.93]
 9: 0x7f8badccefcd v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [/usr/lib64/libnode.so.93]
10: 0x7f8bae06740a v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/lib64/libnode.so.93]
11: 0x7f8bada31cf9  [/usr/lib64/libnode.so.93]
```

The last `vite --debug` message printed is that my `app.css` was loaded.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have an infinite loop or something in your code? It certainly looks like it.

Comment: This sure looks like an older than required nodejs version